# Get ID of canvas element when clicked on

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array, onclick

I want to get the ID of the canvas i click on, but with the code I wrote, I always get the ID of the last canvas. Is it somehow possible to get the value of the multidimensional-array? Should I put the onclick event inside the switch case for that?

```
function drawFigures(figures) {
    var frontDiv = document.createElement("div");
    frontDiv.setAttribute("id","frontDiv");
    document.getElementById('game').appendChild(frontDiv);

    for(var y=0; y<figures.length; y++) {
        fieldDiv = document.createElement("div");
        fieldDiv.setAttribute("class", "figureFieldDiv");
        frontDiv.appendChild(fieldDiv);

        for(var x=0; x<figures[y].length; x++) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", y+","+x);
            canvas.width = 20;
            canvas.height = 20;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            fieldDiv.appendChild(canvas);
            document.getElementById(y+","+x).onclick = function() {console.log(y+","+x)}, false;
            switch(figures[y][x]) {

                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
                    ctx.arc(canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,0,360);
                    ctx.fill();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
                    ctx.arc(canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,0,360);
                    ctx.fill();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0";
                    ctx.arc(canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,0,360);
                    ctx.fill();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
                    ctx.arc(canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,0,360);
                    ctx.fill();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0FF";
                    ctx.arc(canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,canvas.width/3,0,360);
                    ctx.fill();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you've described one way is to use the closure, like that:

```
var id = y + "," + x;
(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {
        console.log(id);
    };
})(id);
```

However, it is always easier to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (or `AttachEvent` for IE) instead:

```
document.getElementById(y+","+x).addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
}, false);
```

Comment: Nice thank you for the advice with the `addEventListener`, this works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

```
var cElements = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
for (var i = 0; i < cElements.length; i++) {
    cElements[i].onclick = getId;
}

function getId(event) {
    console.log(this.id);
}
```